# Deserializing a JSON string to a C# class where JSON class may accept either array / object based on a JSON property

Tags: c#, json

I have to deserialize a JSON string to C# classes inorder to bind to a grid. I have implemented the respective classes in C#. But at a particular instance, this fails because the JSON property will be either an array or an object. Please check a part of the string.

I have created ItemList class with 3 properties IL1 , Name and another object class "Item". However, you can see that when the property "Name" is Rubber, I should have List of Item class as a property rather than Item object. When it is Rubber, it returns array of 2 items.

```
 "ItemList": [
{
  "@IL1": "Yes",
  "@Name": "Pencil"
  "Item": {
    "@ItemType": "Pencil",
    "@Item2": "1A7716744F7048ACA2549BE93F0A2BF1",        
    "aimLink": {
      "@id": "1A7716744F7048ACA2549BE93F0A2BF1",
      "@DisplayText": "P00001"         
    }
  }
},
{
  "@IL1": "Yes",
  "@Name": "Pen",    
  "Item": {
    "@ItemType": "Pen",
    "@Item2": "AE067F7EDB6147C09AED243C1F7FAD25",        
    "aimLink": {
      "@id": "AE067F7EDB6147C09AED243C1F7FAD25",
      "@DisplayText": "5100010654120001
    }
  }
},
{
  "@IL1": "Yes",
  "@Name": "Rubber",     
  "Item": [
    {
      "@ItemType": "Rubber",
      "@ItemGID": "622025629037499394DF092DA16BAB7F",          
      "aimLink": {
        "@id": "622025629037499394DF092DA16BAB7F",
        "@DisplayText": "12345678-1234-123456-7116#01"
      }
    },
    {
      "@ItemType": "Rubber",
      "@ItemGID": "F336F65F8E014E80B84A2312F829493C"
      "aimLink": {
        "@id": "F336F65F8E014E80B84A2312F829493C",
        "@DisplayText": "12345678-1234-123456-7116#14"
      }
    }
  ]
}
 ],
```

How can I parse this to a C# class effectively and the easiest way to get this done?

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: The best thing to do is to fix the JSON so that it is unambiguous.

Comment: if its the same object coming single or collection then its possible, you can check if jobject  then deserialize to object otherwise to list or array

Comment: What serializer are you using?  Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a. Json.Net)?

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this issue by making your custom `JsonConverter` and you can use below to convert single value to array then mark `Item` property with the `JsonConverter` attribute

```
public class SingleValueArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object retVal = new Object();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
            retVal = new List<T>() { instance };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

let's assume this your `ItemList` class

```
public class ItemList
{
    public string @IL1 { get; set; }
    public string @Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueArrayConverter<Item>))]
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string @ItemType { get; set; }
    public string @Item2 { get; set; }
    public AimLink aimLink { get; set; }
}

public class AimLink
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anas. That worked.  I have 1 more clarification. I am deserializing using this  code   -
     JObject studentObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
     var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Archive>(jsonString);                                      If my json string looks like this , how can I extract the Archive part only                                          
     {"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8"},
      "?xml-stylesheet":"type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"./xslt/Archive.xslt\"",
       "Archive":{"@DateTimeCreated":"2021-03-08T18:17:31",.....................

Comment: make archive inside another class like that then `var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);`
 `public class Rootobject
    {
        public Archive Archive { get; set; }
    }

    public class Archive
    {
        public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom `JsonConverter` (e.g. `ItemConverter`) and mark `Item` property with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverter))]` attribute